# Not all code paths return a value when they should

Tags: c#, error-handling, file-handling

Trying to complete a stock system in a console application and thus I am stuck on this part, to make sure that a user can't have a duplicate 8 digit long ID number, my issue is as follows.

Basically I am unsure why this code will not work, I'm probably missing a very obvious piece of code here, help would be appreciated, have tried changing values around already so have more than likely overlooked a value.

```
static int checkIDNumber(int ID)
{
    // Check the number passed in & then loop through all the lines...
    // If number is taken then output error, because id exists already
    // Else allow the value to be used in the stock system.

    int IDNumber = ID;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
    {
        string lineValues;

        while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

            if (lineValues.Contains(IDNumber.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id number is currently already taken.");
            }
            else
            {
                return IDNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I pass in my value from this line in another procedure where it is defined in the local scope.

```
stockID = checkIDNumber(stockID);
```

Here is the full code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char menuOption = '0';

        while (menuOption != '3')
        {
            DisplayMenuOption();
            menuOption = GetMenuOption();

            switch (menuOption)
            {
                case '1':
                    AddStock();
                    break;

                case '2':
                    CheckStock();
                    break;

                case '3':
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid option");
                    break;

            }
        }


            // Keep it all happy for a screenshot ;)
            Console.ReadLine();

    }

    static void DisplayMenuOption()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to Add Stock(1) or Check Stock(2) or Exit(3)?");
    }

    static void DisplayStockOption()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to search by ID(1) or by Name(2), Delete current stock(3) or Exit(4)?");
    }

    static char GetMenuOption()
    {

        char userChoice = '0';

        userChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        return userChoice;
    }

    static void CheckStock()
    {
        char menuOption = 'a';
        while (menuOption != '4')
        {
            DisplayStockOption();
            menuOption = GetMenuOption();

            switch (menuOption)
            {
                case '1':
                    SearchID();
                    break;

                case '2':
                    SearchName();
                    break;

                case '3':
                    RemoveStock();
                    break;

                case '4':
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid option");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    static void RemoveStock()
    {
        List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
        string lineValues = "";
        bool found = false;
        int ID = 0;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
        {

            Console.Write("Please enter the ID number to delete: ");
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

                if (lineValues.Contains(ID.ToString()) == false)
                {
                    tempList.Add(lineValues);
                }
                else
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (found == true)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Stockfile.txt", false))
            {
                for (int i=0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
                {
                    sw.Write(tempList[i]);
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void SearchName()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
        {
            string name;

            Console.Write("Please enter the name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();


            while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {

                string lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

                if (lineValues.Contains(name))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", lineValues);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist in this stock system!",name); // Could try to match a similar string incase of spelling errors here, although after looking at it it may be a bit far for what is being required now, but in the real world application this would be a must else people would mistype words thus not having an exact match.
                }
            }
        }
   }



        static void SearchID()
    {

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
        {
            int IDNumber;
            string lineValues;

            Console.Write("Please enter the ID number: ");
            IDNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {

                lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

                if (lineValues.Contains(IDNumber.ToString()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", lineValues);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} does not exist in this stock system!", IDNumber); // Could try to match a similar string incase of spelling errors here, although after looking at it it may be a bit far for what is being required now, but in the real world application this would be a must else people would mistype words thus not having an exact match.
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static int checkIDNumber(int ID)
    {
        // Check the number passed in & then loop through all the lines...
        // If number is taken then output error, becuase id exists already
        // Else allow the value to be used in the stock system.


        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
        {
            int IDNumber;
            string lineValues;

            Console.Write("Please enter the ID number: ");
            IDNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {

                lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

                if (lineValues.Contains(IDNumber.ToString()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Id number is currently already taken.");
                }
                else
                {
                    ID = IDNumber;
                    return ID;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    static void AddStock(int IDNumber)
    {

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Stockfile.txt", true))
        {
            int stockID = 0;
            int stockQuantity = 0;
            double stockPrice = 0.00;
            string stockName = "";
            string s = ""; // Being Lazy here, to convert to when needed.

            while (stockID.ToString().Length != 8)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the stock ID number: ");
                stockID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            }

            s = stockID.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t"); // Will only accept an 8 figure digit so is safe to have a single value here.

            while (stockName.Length <= 2) // No fancy brands here......
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the name of the stock: ");
                stockName = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            s = stockName;
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            while (stockQuantity < 1) // Running a small shop here...
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the quanity of stock: ");
                stockQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            s = stockQuantity.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            while (stockPrice < 0.01) // Running a very small shop....
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter the price of the stock: ");
                stockPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            s = stockPrice.ToString();
            sw.Write(s + "\t");

            sw.WriteLine(); // TO create the new line.....

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, what value are you returning in the `if (lineValues.Contains(IDNumber.ToString()))` block? Also, what if the while loop never runs?

Comment: Or better what if your files contains only the same ID? The compiler cannot know and don't need to know. You have condition that leads to the function exit point without a value to return.

Comment: @Robertgold One thing to recognize is that the while loop is only being executed once (unless the first value is matching). Putting the return statement within the while loop is stopping it from continuing through all of the lines in the stream.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're only returning a value from inside the `else` block.

Your method needs to return a value regardless of which path the program takes through your code.   You can fix this in any number of ways, depending on your requirements.  For instance, you can have a "catch-all" return value at the bottom of the method so that if it passes through all your tests (i.e. `if` blocks) and reaches the bottom, as long as that's a meaningful result, it will return the catch-all value.

Alternatively, you could just make sure you put a `return` statement inside each of the code paths.  For that, you'd need to add a `return` in the `if` portion of your `if` block, but you'd likely also still need a return outside of your `while` loop since that may never execute.

Again, it all depends on your needs.

Comment: So in essence there is no way to do this without having multiple return statements? As I have been told it is bad practice to get used to having more than one return statement.

Comment: You can do it with one return statement.  The way you do that is create a variable at the top of the method, and just set it wherever you need to set it, then return that variable at the end of the method.  In my experience, it's not a bad practice to have multiple returns if it makes your code more concise and readable, and more-importantly, less brittle or error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

It's at least logically possible that the file contains nothing but the ID. For example, if I enter "10" as an ID and the file is:

```
10
10
10
10
...
```

It might be the case that you know that that'll never *actually* happen, but the compiler can't really *prove* that it won't. From the compiler's "perspective," there's not really a difference between "might happen" and "can't prove that it won't happen."

Also, your logic is wrong. If you know that the user requested a duplicate ID, you don't need to check the rest of the file - you already know it's a duplicate.

Right now, if the first line of the file isn't the ID they requested, it'll allow the user to take it. For example, if the user requested "9" as an ID and the file is as follows:

```
3 -- It only actually checks this line
5
9 -- Obviously the ID is already taken here but it'll never check this line
2
1
```

See my comments below:

```
// I'd suggest making this "bool" - they already know what the ID number is,
// so there's no point in returning it back to them
static int checkIDNumber(int ID)
{
    // Check the number passed in & then loop through all the lines...
    // If number is taken then output error, because id exists already
    // Else allow the value to be used in the stock system.

    int IDNumber = ID;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Stockfile.txt"))
    {

        string lineValues;

        // In general, you shouldn't explicitly compare to "true" or "false."
        // Just write this as "!sr.EndOfStream"
        while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
        {

            lineValues = sr.ReadLine();

            if (lineValues.Contains(IDNumber.ToString()))
            {
                // In this case, you don't have to bother checking the rest of the file
                // since you already know that the ID is taken
                Console.WriteLine("Id number is currently already taken.");

            }
            else
            {
                // You actually can't return that at this point - you need to check
                // the *entire* file before you conclude that it's not a duplicate
                return IDNumber;
            }
        }

    }
}
```